# block url path patterns with alb ingress rules

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an alb ingress controller in which I don't want to allow access to certain paths from the external side. example path like actuator which is mounted to monitor services internally.

I see every ingress rule routing request to serve in the background. how can I return 403 from ingress itself?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using annotations.

For example as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig":
      { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-example-com-alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: my-security-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy : "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: myhost.example.com
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/mycustomhealthpath/"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: "HTTP"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: "15"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: "http"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: "3"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-403: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"403","messageBody":"403 External access to endpoint not allowed"}}
  name: login
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /block/access/to/this/path
        backend:
          serviceName: response-403
          servicePort: use-annotation
      - backend:
          serviceName: ssl-redirect
          servicePort: use-annotation
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.example.com
```

Notice that in this example the URI and URL are fictional.

Reference: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#traffic-routing.

In this example, the `apiVersion` of the Kubernetes ingress manifest uses the `extentions/v1beta1` API group; the example can be adapted to fit the stable API group, the convention does not change.

Last but not least, I did not check what is the minimum version of the ingress-controller that does support this convention. In this example, I rely on version 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This method works for me.

Comment: You are welcome and glad that it helped you :D